# Скажите, в JS используются и одинарные, и двойные кавычки?

Tags: javascript

Скажите, в JS используются и одинарные, и двойные кавычки?

Comment: Что значит *используются*?

Comment: да. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: и еще вот такие: `

Comment: да, оба варианта и разницы никакой. Еще есть бектикиты https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings для шаблонов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для строк в js используются:

- ' - одинарные
- " - двойные
- ` - обратные

```
var A = 'A'
var B = "B"
var C = `пример
    обратных
    ${A}
    ${B}
`
```

однако, принято использовать одинарные в `js` двойные в `html`.
и уж точно не смешивать, либо ' либо ".

Comment: Ну например в JSON строго двойные)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME но JSON это и не JS